# understanding one of "jMeter - Reducing resource requirements" recommendation

Tags: jmeter

Can somebody please explain following recommendation on http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#lean_mean

`Rather than using lots of similar samplers, use the same sampler in a loop, and use variables (CSV Data Set) to vary the sample. Or perhaps use the Access Log Sampler. [The Include Controller does not help here, as it adds all the test elements in the file to the test plan.]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is intended to fix the following:

Suppose you have 2 requests:

> test?name=toto
>
> test?name=titi

A basic and bad way to do it would be to create 2 Http Requests one with each request above.

What recommandation says is:

- create 1 Http Request with:

> test?name=${value}

And create a CSV Dataset with a one column data and a variable named:

> value

CSV file will contain:

- toto
- titi

And use 2 iterations, which will do exactly the same.

Of course here you have 2 rows, but in real life you would have hundreds or thousands.